# Create Generic Method that accepts a List with custom object types and access similar properties

Tags: c#, search

I am creating a search algorithm that searches through a list with custom objects I have created. They share similar properties, but I can not seem to "implicitly" access these properties..? An example:

```
public class Exit{
    int ID {get;set;}
}

public class Room{
    int ID {get;set;}
}

static void Main(string[] args){
    List<Exit> exits = new List<Exit>();
    List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();

    // added numerous instances of objects to both lists

    int getExitID = _GetIDFromList(exits, 2);    //example
    int getRoomID = _GetIDFromList(rooms, 7);    //example
}

private int _GetIDFromList<T>(List<T> list, int indexOfList){
    return list[indexOfList].ID;    // this gives me error it can't find ID
}
```

Is this possible? What do I need to modify to what I have to do this??

Thank you.

Comment: Create a common interface which both your classes implement. Then you can easily add a generic constraint ti your method, something like `int _GetIDFromList<T>(List<T> list, int indexOfList) where T: MyInterface`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create interface for it:

```
public interface IId
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Exit : IId
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Room : IId
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}

private int _GetIDFromList<T>(List<T> list, int indexOfList) where T : IId
{
    return list[indexOfList].ID;   
}
```

Or you can use `Reflection` and `Expression` for it:

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, P>> GetGetter<T, P>(string propName)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propName);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, P>>(property, parameter);
    }
```

Retrives int `Id` from type `T` and returns it:

```
    private static int _GetIDFromList<T>(List<T> list, int indexOfList)
    {
        var lambda = GetGetter<T, int>("Id").Compile();
        return lambda(list[indexOfList]);
    }
```

I'm little rewrote your Room class:

```
    public class Room
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
```

And usage:

```
    Console.WriteLine(_GetIDFromList(new List<Room> { new Room { ID = 5 } }, 0));
```

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I am looking for.. I am curious.. I haven't messed with Interfaces at at, but they seem like the equivalent for header files in C/C++ and declaration of functions etc...?

Comment: @user3712563 Nope, `interface` doesn't seem like header files C++. Header files seem like `using` in C#. For more details you can read about it in the SO: [the first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744105/are-c-header-h-files-like-interfaces-in-c-java) and [the second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697454/interfaces-and-headers)